# How to populate WrapPanel from several sources in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need something like this:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Person.Name}" Style="style1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Project.Name}" Style="style2" />
    foreach item in {Binding Path=Tags}
    {
        <TextBlock Text={Binding item.Name} Style="style3" />
    }
</WrapPanel>
```

I have done it through code, but I would prefer to have it in XAML, as this is somewhat common and basic functionality + I want to see it in designer with my sample data to style it well.

I tried to use `ItemsControl` to populate the collection, but it always creates it's own panel, which obviously breaks wrapping.

I think one could also request to throw another collection there.

How to do it without writing code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use an items control with the `WrapPanel` as the [`ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx)?  For multiple sources you can use the [`CompositeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) to group them to display in your itemscontrol.

Comment: I was dreaming about having something like this. I'm going to test it tomorrow.

Comment: It works like a charm. `CompositeCollection` is great, thanks a lot!